# SQL Server: best account for dbo user?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, sql-server-2008, user-management, database-administration

What is the best account for dbo user? I mean that if I use personal AD account for database owner, and if this account is removed from AD (e.g if I leave my job), these databases are not accessible. I have heard that there is also problems using "sa" account in dbo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dbo is a "user" (a security principal at the database level) and is listed in [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx)

It isn't the database owner mentioned in [sys.databases.owner_sid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx). This column is at the server level and matches an entry in [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx), specifically the sid column.

For ease of use, just make the owner `sa`. There are no major issues with doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate account for that, something like SQLadmin. Give it only the permissions it needs in AD, and whatever it needs for SQL.